# iOS JSON decoder data in not in correct format error

Tags: ios, json, swift, vapor

I'm building a simple app which fetches json data from server and present it to user.I have a json file in vapor Public directory and when I try to parse it in iOS app it gives an error data is in incorrect format.I have converted the json file to swift struct by using json to swift online convertor.

But when I test the server response with postman it gives me the json file.In iOS app it gives me an error.I was able to fetch the data if I print it it gives 1372 bytes but when I try to parse it gives me an error that data is incorrect format

I'm getting following error

typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

my json file

```
{
 "memes": [
    {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-53-300x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-53.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-1-300x210.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-1.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-54-300x250.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-54.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-55-300x269.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-55.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-56.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-56.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-57.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-57.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-58.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-58.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-8.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-8.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-59.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-59.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-66.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-66.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/download.jpg",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/download.jpg"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-12-300x281.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-12.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-13-300x281.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-13.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-14-240x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-14.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-61.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-61.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-62.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-62.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-17-300x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-17.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-18-252x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-18.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-19-300x281.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-19.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-20-249x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-20.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-21-300x233.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-21.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-63.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-63.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-64.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-64.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-24-300x150.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-24.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-25-289x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-25.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-27.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-27.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-52-300x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-52.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-30-300x221.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-30.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-65.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-65.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-32-300x239.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-32.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-33-300x181.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-33.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-34-300x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-34.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-35-300x250.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-35.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-36-300x269.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-36.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-37-300x210.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-37.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-38-300x292.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-38.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-39-300x167.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-39.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-40-249x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-40.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-41-300x294.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-41.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-42-300x295.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-42.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-43-234x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-43.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-44-300x263.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-44.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-45-300x255.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-45.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-46-300x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-46.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-47.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-47.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-48-300x210.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-48.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-49-249x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-49.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-50-300x300.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-50.png"
       },
       {
        "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-51-300x146.png",
        "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-51.png"
       },

  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/python-2.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/python-development-company/"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/1.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/1.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/3.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/3.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/4-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/4-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/6-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/6-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/7-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/7-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/8-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/8-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/9-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/9-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/10-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/10-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/11-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/11-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/12-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/12-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/13-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/13-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/14-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/14-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/15-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/15-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/16.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/16.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/17.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/17.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/18.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/18.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/19.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/19.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/20.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/20.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/9-1.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/9-1.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/8-1.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/8-1.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/7.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/7.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/12.0.0-1/svg/1f609.svg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/3-2.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/3-2.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/6-1.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/6-1.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Imgur-8801b2-1.png",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Imgur-8801b2-1.png"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/r_389776_tqMPa-1.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/r_389776_tqMPa-1.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2-2.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/2-2.jpg"
  },
  {
   "image": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/4.jpg",
   "url": "https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/4.jpg"
  }
 ]
}
```

Routes.swift file in Vapor

```
import Vapor

    struct Welcome: Codable,Content {
        let memes: [Meme]
    }
    
    
    struct Meme: Codable,Content {
        let image: String
        let url: String?
    }
    
    
    
    
    func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
        
        var m = [Meme]()
        
        var path = app.directory.publicDirectory
        path.append("memes.json")
        print(path)
        
        
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) else {return }
        
        do
        {
            let memess =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
            m = memess.memes
        }
        catch{
            
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        
        
        
        app.get { req in
         
            
            return m
        }
    
       
    }
```

iOS App codable struct file

```
import Foundation

public struct Json4Swift_Base : Codable {
public    let memes : [Memes]?

  public   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case memes = "memes"
    }

   public  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        memes = try values.decodeIfPresent([Memes].self, forKey: .memes)
    }

}


public struct Memes : Codable {
 public    let image : String?
   public  let url : String?

   public  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case image = "image"
        case url = "url"
    }

 public    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        image = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .image)
        url = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .url)
    }

}
```

NetworkService file

```
import Foundation


public class NetworkService
{
    
  public  static let sharedobj = NetworkService()
    
  public  let url = URL(string:"http://127.0.0.1:8080")
    
  public   let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    
 public func getMemes(onSucces:@escaping([Memes],Error?)->Void)
    {
       let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
            
            
            do
            {
                let items = try JSONDecoder().decode(Json4Swift_Base.self, from: data!)
                onSucces(items.memes!,error)
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            
            
            
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Change `print(error.localizedDescription)` to `print(error)` to get a more detailed and helpful error message

Comment: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: The JSON matches the structs. The error says the root object is an array. Is this the real JSON? By the way most of the contents of the structs is redundant. For example you can reduce `Json4Swift_Base` to `public struct Json4Swift_Base : Decodable { public let memes : [Memes] }` You get the `CodingKeys` and the `init` method else for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Vapor code you decode the file and then extract only the array to a property so assuming that this is what you encode and send to the client then you only receive the array.

Like this

```
"[
{
    "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-53-300x300.png",
    "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-53.png"
   },
   {
    "image": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-1-300x210.png",
    "url": "https://www.testbytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Untitled-1.png"
   },
   ...
]"
```

So in your client you should decode the array only

```
let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Memes].self, from: data!)
```

And you don't need `init(from:)` or a CodingKey enum here.